# Run function on change of a reactive var

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a template that looks as follows:

```
Template['Users.list'].hooks({
  created: function () {
    this.perPage = new ReactiveVar(10);
  },
  rendered: function () {
    this.pageResults = _.throttle(() => {
      const space = this.$('.content').innerHeight() - this.$('.ifl-user-list >:not(".user-item")').outerHeight();
      this.perPage.set(Math.ceil(space / $(this.find('.user-item')).outerHeight()));

    }, 200).bind(this);
    $(window).on('resize', this.pageResults);
  },
  destroyed: function () {
    $(window).off('resize', this.pageResults);
  }
});
```

Essentially, whenever `perPage` is changed, I want to do a call to change the amount of data subscribed to. I've tried using `this.autorun` function, but it does not seem to be called when the reactive var changes.

Is there a way to watch this reactive var and run a function when it is changed?

Comment: Yes you can, this is shown in the [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/tracker_autorun) (ok, it's a `Session` variable, but it's the same thing).  Can you add your `autorun` code, and your `subscribe` code?

Comment: Since it a reactiveVar its already tracked for changes. Easiest way will be write a helper Using this reactive var and Helper Function will be invoked every time the variable changes.